# inputs loaded through ajax don't appear in request body

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel-5

I have form, with two hidden inputs and submit button in my bootstrap modal

```
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/tours/23/edit" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="editVideoForm">
    <div class="modal-body modal-video-cont">
        <div class="modal-body-container">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-7">
            <input class="btn green pull-left ddf_button_pad" name="update_video_form" type="submit" value="Save">

            <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button" class="btn green btn-outline pull-right ddf_button_pad">Cancel</button>

            <input class="position-input" id="editVidTempPos" name="template_position" type="hidden">
            <input id="editVidType" name="type" type="hidden" value="video">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

in `<div class="modal-body-container">` element I load content(which contains radio buttons) through ajax(works fine)

```
<input type="radio" class="blockRadio video-input" name="resource" data-position="" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/videos/424046_00_05_MM30_exercisefiles.mp4" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">

<input type="radio" class="blockRadio video-input" name="resource" data-position="" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/videos/424046_00_05_MM30_exercisefiles.mp4" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
```

however when i submit form, i don't see these radio elements in request body(there should be `resource` index)

```
"_token" => "FF1zRnyORk9BzBUIWTj13PI06SZxYld1iLfpNZ0e"
"template_position" => "6"
"type" => "video"
```

these inputs appears in DOM tree. before send form

```
$( "#editVideoForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$('#edit-vid').modal('hide');
var formdata = $(this).serialize();
```

`$(this).serialize()` doesn't see that new inputs. console log
`_token=FF1zRnyORk9BzBUIWTj13PI06SZxYld1iLfpNZ0e&template_position=6&type=video`

**UPDATE**

before send form, this event fires

```
event.preventDefault();
    $('#edit-vid').modal('hide');
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    var formUrl = $(this).attr('action');
    var position = $('#editVidTempPos').val();
    console.log('#placeForPos' + position);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: formUrl,
        data: formdata,
        beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
            $('#placeForPos' + position).html('<div class="mt-overlay-2 margin-top-10">' +
                    '<div class="loader_wrapper">' +
                    '<img class="loader" src="/images/loader.gif" alt="Loader" />' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>');
            //console.log(xhr);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#placeForPos' + position).html(data);
            swal({title: "Video for position " +position+ " changed",type: "success"});

        },
        error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseCode);
```

when it serialized, it doesn't see new inputs, but if I remove this event, new inputs are shown

Comment: That most likely either means that a) your new elements did _not_ get appended to the form as you think (verify that in DOM inspector, that they are actually _inside_ the form), or that b) you are not sending the form “the normal way”, but have some JS/Ajax that builds the request, and doesn’t take those new fields into account.

Comment: thanks for reply. a) they appear in DOM tree b) yes, there are some js before send(sorry for not mention that before, I'm not the only one who works on the project). I update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with comment by @CBroe

Taking it further you could try this this code to serialize and post your form:

```
$("#editVideoForm").submit(function (e) { 
    var frm = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (response)
        {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function () { 
            alert('error')
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

- You need JQUERY
- This fraction of code will do the post asynchronously
- If asynchronous post is not what you require, use the following line in the Browser console to verify that the form is in the correct syntax (Thereafter you will have to find and overwrite the actual code that is posting your form in the wrong way):

```
alert(JSON.stringify($("#editVideoForm").serialize()); //UNTESTED
```

**EDIT**

Upon further inspection I see that the two inputs you are adding dynamically are radio inputs. So give one of them the checked attribute:

```
<input type="radio" checked id= .......... //Focus on checked attribute
```

Or, of course, if you want the text in the inputs change the type to text:

```
<input type="text" ...... //Rest of tag omitted
```

**EDIT2**

Checkout this snipper - an unchecked radio does not get serialized.

Also, my sincere apologies as I have told you the attribute is "selected" where it is in fact "checked" **Fixed**

```js
$().ready(function () {
  
  $('#serialize1').click(function () {
    alert(JSON.stringify($("#frmNotselect").serialize()));
  });
  
  $('#serialize2').click(function () {
    
    $("#frmSelect input[type='radio']").first().attr('checked', true);
    
    
    alert(JSON.stringify($("#frmSelect").serialize()));
  });
  
  $('#serialize3').click(function () {
    
$("#frmSelect").find("input[type='radio']").first().prop('checked', true);
    
    
    alert(JSON.stringify($("#frmSelect").serialize()));
  });
  
  $('#serialize4').click(function () {
    
    
    $("#frmSelect").find('input[type="radio"]').attr('type', 'text');
    
    alert(JSON.stringify($("#frmSelect").serialize()));
  });
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='frmNotselect'>
  <div>
    <h4>Not Selected</h4>
    <input type='radio' value='someValue' name='someName' />
    <input type='button' value='serialize' id='serialize1' />
  </div>
</form>

<form id='frmSelect'>
  <div>
    <h4>Selected</h4>
    <label>Normal Type</label>
    <input type='radio' checked value='someValue' name='resource' />
    <br/>
        <label>http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/videos/424046_00_05_MM30_exercisefiles.mp4</label>
    <input type='radio' checked value='http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/videos/424046_00_05_MM30_exercisefiles.mp4' name='resource'/>
    
    <input type='button' value='serialize' id='serialize2' />
    <input type='button' id='serialize3' value='force checked then serialize' />
    <input type='button' value='Convert to txt' id='serialize4' />
    
  </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT3**

Okay, so have a look at that snippet again. It has been updated to show you that you can't have more than one radio checked at one point in time. The HTML just doesn't allow it.

So I added a function that converts it to text and still, you can't have two text inputs with the same name - only one of them gets posted.

***Point to make here is that the radio's must be used for radio purposes.  These fields should be text or hidden fields with unique names to get posted correctly***

Comment: thanks for reply) I updated question, and I do somethig like this, but it doesn't  work

Comment: Check my edit, serialize in the browser console again and give us an update!

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringify($("#editVideoForm").serialize()))` i try this, it doesn't show new inputs `_token=FF1zRnyORk9BzBUIWTj13PI06SZxYld1iLfpNZ0e&template_position=6&type=video`

Comment: Sure enough. I believe this is because neither of these radio buttons are selected - try adding the selected attribute.

Comment: Checked - Radio's aren't checked. The snippet shows you what happens... See if you can get somewhere and report back!

Comment: thank you so much for your help, i added `checked` to input, but it does't help. I updated question

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/tours/23/edit" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="editVideoForm">
<div class="modal-body modal-video-cont">
    <div class="modal-body-container">
<input type="radio" class="blockRadio video-input" name="resource" data-position="" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/videos/424046_00_05_MM30_exercisefiles.mp4" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">

<input type="radio" class="blockRadio video-input" name="resource" data-position="" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/videos/424046_00_05_MM30_exercisefiles.mp4" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-7">
        <input class="btn green pull-left ddf_button_pad" name="update_video_form" type="submit" value="Save">

        <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button" class="btn green btn-outline pull-right ddf_button_pad">Cancel</button>

        <input class="position-input" id="editVidTempPos" name="template_position" type="hidden">
        <input id="editVidType" name="type" type="hidden" value="video">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Please Check first from console your hidden field is added or not.  And Also check Your form is serialized proper or not.

Comment: thaks for reply, my hidden fields are added. I serialize form, but it doesn't see new inputs, I updated question